# manga where female lead died in her world and got reincarnated into a girl who got poisoned by her stepmother and stepsister

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation, cultivation

Manga where female lead died in her world and reincarnated in the body of a girl who got poisoned by her stepmother and stepsister and because of the poison her body has bad odor but female lead cured her poison.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you remember any details of the appearance of any characters, or the setting?

Comment: What colour was the female lead's hair?

Comment: I just remember that female lead died in her world and was reincarnated into the body of a girl whose stepmother and stepsister poisoned her, and as a result, her body has a bad odour. She was also engaged to the emperor's son, but her fiance didn't like her because of her body odour, and he was also having an affair with her stepsister

Answer (score 2):

This is the manhua  *The Consort Who's a Bloodthirsty Doctor*, also known as *Princess is a Bloodthirsty Surgeon*, by Bi Ciyuan Comics.

Summary from Bilibili Comics:

> The Consort Who's a Bloodthirsty Doctor: In her past life, before a
> plane crash, she was a genius in both medicine and poison. In this
> life, she is the legitimate daughter of a noble family whose fiancé
> has been snatched by her illegitimate sister. Right after entering her
> new life, she finds herself already infected with a serious case of
> body odor. The younger sisters of the original host's body scorn her,
> and she has found out that the original host died because she hit her
> head against the railing when her fiancé slapped her. Now that she has
> replaced the previous host, she will not allow these despicable
> villains to continue opressing her. Why does the Cold-faced Prince,
> known as the War King of Hell, seem so different from the rumors?
> Regardless, whoever that insults her, frames her, or tries to
> assassinate her must die!

Official English translations are available.

Found by searching "reincarnation manga poison body odor"
on Google.