# manga where female lead died in her world and got reincarnated into a girl who got poisoned by her stepmother and stepsister and has bad body odour

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga, reincarnation, female-characters

**female lead died in her world and was reincarnated into the body of a girl whose stepmother and stepsister poisoned her, and as a result, her body has a bad odour. She was also engaged to the emperor's son, but her fiance didn't like her because of her body odour, and he was also having an affair with her stepsister**.

Comment: Are you the same person as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/265925/manga-where-female-lead-died-in-her-world-and-got-reincarnated-into-a-girl-who-g?

Comment: Yes i am the same person

Comment: Ah, you can merge your accounts as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts so that you get credit for the points you earned the last time you asked this question.